# I am completely new to C programming and keep getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c

This is for a hotel reservation system, that take a .txt file that contains lines of int string string int which it then reads and put into an array of type room... while scanning it keeps giving me segmentation fault... this is for class and i dont want a ready code to leech of but i just dont get why i keep getting segmentation... :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



typedef struct{
    int num; 
    char first[100];
    char last[100]; 
    int type;
    }room;

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

    FILE * myFile;

    if(argc !=2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        myFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");

        if (myFile==NULL){

            fprintf(stderr, "no open!!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        }


        // counter to add elements to my array
        int i = 0;

        char c;
        //array of room with the 150 rooms in it...
        room * rooms = malloc(150 * sizeof(room));

        while ((c = getc(myFile)) != EOF ){

            fscanf(myFile, "%d", rooms[i].num);
            printf("the room num is: %d", rooms[i].num);
            fscanf(myFile, "%s", rooms[i].first);
            fscanf(myFile, "%s", rooms[i].last);
            fscanf(myFile, "%d", rooms[i].type);
            i++;

        }
        fclose(myFile);


}
```

Here is what i fixed in my code and worked but it is literally skipping the fist integer in the .txt file that it reads from... it just reads a zero when it should be a 1 so i noticed that the "(c = getc(myFile)) != EOF" was my problem, it is skipping the first integer it is supposed to read :/

```
while ((c = getc(myFile)) != EOF ){


            fscanf(myFile, "%d", &rooms[i].num);
            fscanf(myFile, "%s", rooms[i].first);
            fscanf(myFile, "%s", rooms[i].last);
            fscanf(myFile, "%d", &rooms[i].type);

            printf("the room num is: %d and is occupied by %s %s and it is a                                      %d\n", rooms[i].num, rooms[i].first, rooms[i].last, rooms[i].type);
            i++;

        }
```

The .txt file's first line is as follows:
1 carri alston 0

Comment: if you're on linux, `gdb` is your friend. :-)

Comment: i am running on a university cluster, can i use gdp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
fscanf(myFile, "%d", rooms[i].num);
```

should be

```
fscanf(myFile, "%d", &rooms[i].num);
```

same with the `type` thing.

Along with that, you should always check the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure proper `scan`ning.

also, you need to put a check on the value of `i` so that it should not access out of bound memory.

Comment: @user2116459 as far as I can see, `num` is not a pointer. :-)

Comment: @user2116459, `rooms` is a pointer (to a `room`).  `rooms[i]` is a `room`.  `rooms[i].num` is an `int`.

Comment: @user2116459, you need to do the same thing with `rooms[i].type`.

Comment: it appears i have some issues with winscp... i am working on sublime and when ever i save and then check the file on the cluster, i find out that not all changes are being applied... i will rewrite the code and use ur suggestions and reply back..